# Why are the sap-icons broken when I use a custom theme?

Tags: sapui5, ui5-tooling

I have a OpenUI5 project where I want to add a custom theme.

The theme is coming from a npm package, so I included it in `package.json` like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "webui-theme-my_eservice": "^1.12.1"
}
```

Then I configured the build command from [ui5-cli](https://sap.github.io/ui5-tooling/v3/pages/CLI/) to also build this into the output:

```
ui5 build --dest=../../webapp --clean-dest --include-dependency=webui-theme-my_eservice
```

Finally, I apply my custom theme in `index.html`:

```
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
    src="https://sdk.openui5.org/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    data-sap-ui-theme="my_eservice"
    data-sap-ui-theme-roots='{
        "my_eservice" : "./resources"
    }'
    ...>
```

When I run the build output on a server, the color scheme and component styles of my custom theme are **correctly applied**. However, it seems that all references to [UI5 Icons](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/m/demokit/iconExplorer/webapp/index.html#/overview/SAP-icons/?tab=grid&icon=visits&search=visits) are broken:

```
<Button
    icon="sap-icon://visits" />
```

ends up displaying as

[image: screenshot]

All icons are displayed as outlined rectangles, and the network log in the developer tools shows errors like:

[image: screenshot of dev tools]

It appears that the fallback mechanism doesn't work, as the application only is looking for the icons in the custom theme. From my understanding, once a resource is not available in the custom theme, it should fallback to the default theme and pick up the resources from there.

When I switch to a default theme, all icons display as they should. 
 What do I need to get both my custom theme and the icons working?

Comment: Last time that happened to me I had to rebuild the theme from the theme designer.